python datetime timezone converted is not really changing anything except the timezone label?
I am US/Pacific timezone (and my devices are too).
import time
import pytz
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timezone
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

tz_pac = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
dt_pac = tz_pac.localize(datetime(2024, 2, 25))
print(dt_pac)
# datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 25, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>)

epoch_pac = int(dt_pac.strftime('%s'))
print(epoch_pac)
# 1708848000

Yes, this is correct.
tz_est = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
dt_est = tz_est.normalize(dt_pac)
print(dt_est)
datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 25, 3, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EST-1 day, 19:00:00 STD>)

Yes, it was 3:00 am in the Eastern timezone, when it was midnight Pacific timezone.
print(int(dt_est.strftime('%s')))
# 1708858800 <= this is epoch 3:00 am Pacific (not Eastern)

So why are the epochs different?
tried searching and tried to figure it out myself...
NOTE: Please don't use datetime.now(), I need to convert certain times that are not right now. Thank you!

Don't use strftime('%s'), use .timestamp().

Also, use zoneinfo (and tzdata if you're on Windows). pytz is deprecated and timezone rules might be out-of-date.
